# ExpressionEngine Related Pages Navigation

Tags: navigation, expressionengine

I have a problem with ExpressionEngine (specifically v2.5.2) and the EE forums are closed today for some reason which is the reason I am posting here. Hopefully someone can help out anyway.

I have a channel set up in EE called "Static Pages" which contains all the data for my static pages (Obviously). The channel also has a relationship field called {static_parent_page}. I used this relationship field to build my navigation so you can have subpages under which ever page you choose as the parent page using this relationship field.

eg. I create a page called "Parent Page" and another two pages called "Subpage 1" and "Subpage 2" and on the Subpage 1 & 2 entries I set "Parent Page" in the {static_parent_page} field and they appear in the navigation like this:

-Parent Page
---Sub Page 1
---Sub Page 2

Anyway, I hope that makes sense.

Onto my problem. I want to be able to go to the "Parent Page", which has two columns, one is a sidebar and the other is the main content. In the sidebar I want a link to the Parent Page at the top and underneath that links to the related subpages as well.

I believe I have sorted that out my using {related_entries} tag but when I go to one of the sub pages the parent page link is still displayed but the other related subpages disappear.

SO...(I think I have made this more complex than it needs to be, apologies) basically I want the sidebar to display:

-Parent Page
---Sub Page 1
---Sub Page 2

Regardless of whether you are on the "Parent Page", "Sub Page 1" or "Sub Page 2".

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
Ben

Answer (score 1):

Without being able to see your template code, I would say try to set dynamic="off" in the template.

Comment: Without template code we won't be able to help you much, have you considered using a navigation management module such as navee?

Answer (score 0):

Purchase and use the [Structure Module](http://buildwithstructure.com/). It was built for the exact purpose you describe, including generating navigation dynamically.

Side note: In EE 2+, the dynamic parameter needs to be set to "no" instead of "off."